# Why does my client only receive data from node.js after a client page refresh?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-mysql

This is very odd. Here is the abridged output of my log:

```
info  - socket.io started
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized D7J-52pdfYAtijFhFxh7
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/D7J-52pdfYAtijFhFxh7
debug - set heartbeat interval for client D7J-52pdfYAtijFhFxh7
debug - client authorized for
debug - websocket writing 1::
establishing db connection.
Attaching new socket D7J-52pdfYAtijFhFxh7 to namespace /59a0747b-50b3-46c9-be7e-3d74fd513fcf for actID: 1.
```

```
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 6eUwG7fH-CG3vx3CFxh8
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/websocket/6eUwG7fH-CG3vx3CFxh8
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 6eUwG7fH-CG3vx3CFxh8
debug - client authorized for
debug - websocket writing 1::
establishing db connection.
debug - client authorized for /59a0747b-50b3-46c9-be7e-3d74fd513fcf
debug - websocket writing 1::/59a0747b-50b3-46c9-be7e-3d74fd513fcf
Attaching new socket 6eUwG7fH-CG3vx3CFxh8 to namespace /59a0747b-50b3-46c9-be7e-3d74fd513fcf for actID: 1.
```

The first block is on initial client connect, which is passing a namespace to socket.io like this: `http://server/59a0747b-50b3-46c9-be7e-3d74fd513fcf`

Please notice that these two lines are blank:

```
debug - client authorized for
debug - websocket writing 1::
```

The second block (all within the same log) occurs after I hit refresh on the client's web page. Same connecting URL, but you'll notice

```
debug - client authorized for /59a0747b-50b3-46c9-be7e-3d74fd513fcf
debug - websocket writing 1::/59a0747b-50b3-46c9-be7e-3d74fd513fcf
```

are displaying the necessary information in order for node to send data to the namespace'd client.

**EDIT:**
<s>I don't understand why I have to refresh the client page in order for the connection to be successfully established, especially when if I investigate the `io.namespaces['/59a0747b-50b3-46c9-be7e-3d74fd513fcf'].sockets` object, the client's socket is listed.</s>
**At no point after the initial client connection is the namespace found anywhere in the io object. Why?**

It may or may not be worth mentioning the db lookup is the very first thing that occurs on client connect and i'm  using node-mysql, but it connecting to a different, remote, server to pull that information.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code, but this type of thing is often caused by sending the reply before your async db lookup has completed.

Comment: Perhaps even simpler:

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
 console.log(io.namespaces);
});


This should have the namespace somewhere in its object, correct?

Comment: Additionally, I don't control the firing of those two debug statements. They seem to come from node/socket automatically when a client connects.